# Optimizing this recursive function (dynamic programming)

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm solving a very simple algorithm problem that requests recursion and memoization. The code below works fine but it doesn't meet the time limitation. Someone advised me to optimize tail recursion, but it is not a tail recursion.. This is just a studying material, not a homework.

Question

• A snail can climb 2m per 1 day if it rains, 1m otherwise.

• The probability of raining per day is 75%.

• Given the number of days(<=1000) and height(<=1000), calculate the probability that the snail can get out of the well (climb more than the height well)

This python code is implemented with recursion and memoization.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

# Probability of success that snails can climb 'targetHeight' within 'days'
def successRate(days, targetHeight):
    global cache

    # edge case
    if targetHeight <= 1:
        return 1
    if days == 1:
        if targetHeight > 2:
            return 0
        elif targetHeight == 2:
            return 0.75
        elif targetHeight == 1:
            return 0.25

    answer = cache[days][targetHeight]

    # if the answer is not previously calculated
    if answer == -1:
        answer = 0.75 * (successRate(days - 1, targetHeight - 2)) + 0.25 * (successRate(days - 1, targetHeight - 1))
        cache[days][targetHeight] = answer

    return answer


height, duration = map(int, input().split())
cache = [[-1 for j in range(height + 1)] for i in range(duration + 1)] # cache initialized as -1
print(round(successRate(duration, height),7))
```

Comment: I didn't encounter the performance issue on my side. Both height=1000 and days=1000 returned less than a second.

Comment: As it should be O(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. So it is just a hint.
For inital part set:

```
# suppose cache is allocated
cache[1][1] = 0.25
cache[1][2] = 0.75
for i in range(3,targetHeight+1):
    cache[1][i] = 0
for i in range(days+1):
    cache[i][1] = 1
    cache[i][0] = 1
```

And then try to rewrite the recursive part using the initialized values (you should iterate bottom-up, likes the below). And finally, return the value of `cache[days][targetHeight]`.

```
for i in range(2, days+1):
    for j in range(2, targetHeight+1):
        cache[i][j] = 0.75 * cache[i-1][j-2] + 0.25 * cache[i-1][j-1]
```